# Increase key repeat speed on Linux and MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard, operating-systems

I am writing a library so trying to support multiple OS.
I am looking to increase the key repeat speed of the return key and down/up arrows. The speed looks pretty limited, maybe repeats about 8 times a second. I am looking for double that if possible. Is there something universal or does each OS have its own mechanism to control this.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the autorepeat rate of single keys is not universally supported.

At least under Linux, you'd need to write your own keyboard driver (or generic input driver for key events) for that.

Und Linux and X, it's possible to set the autorepeat rate of the whole keyboard with the command line tool `xset`, or equivalently using a library to make use of the `XFree86-Misc` or `XKB` protocol extension of the X server.

I don't know how it works under MacOS; my guess is that it works quite differently.